# Unital rings correspondence by a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\phi:R\rightarrow R'$ be a (*not necessarily* unital) ring homomorphism. If $S'$ is a subring of $R'$, it is easy to show that $\phi^{-1}(S')$ is a subring of $R$. But if $S'$ is also unital, will $\phi^{-1}(S')$ be unital as well? In other words, can we always find a multiplicative identity in $\phi^{-1}(S')$?

---

PS: By a subring $S$ of $R$ I mean a subset $S\subseteq R$ such that it is a ring itself under the same operations of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the embedding $2\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$. The inverse image of the codomain, which is unital, is the whole domain, which is not unital.

If you want a surjective homomorphism, consider the trivial homomorphism $R\to\{0\}$. The codomain is unital, but the domain may not be.

Comment: @Easy It’s simply $f(x)=x$

Comment: @Easy You're interested in inverse images: $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Z})=2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Easy That's irrelevant and you didn't ask for a surjective map. If $f\colon A\to B$ is a map and $C\subseteq B$, then $f^{-1}(C)=\{a\in A:f(a)\in C\}$. There's no surjectivity requirement.

Comment: @Easy A counterexample suffices.